# Fetching data from database using python

Tags: python

consider a file (student.dat) storing information about student performance
WAP in python to retrieve the details of those students.
A) Who's name starts with 'A'
B) Who have atleast one 'a' in their name.
C) Display marks

Comment: If the data is in file and is huge then, you may use PySpark to do SQL like operations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could give you a little Idea:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="myusername",
  passwd="mypassword", database="mydatabase")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
print(x)
```